# Call a resource with passed String

Tags: java, android, android-intent, resources

I'm writing an Android native app which should show the user 360 degree panoramas of multiple camping van models. I have selection lists, which lead to exact models.

Instead of defining activities for each of them, I've tried to pass a variable to the panorama-activity to call the requested image. But I'm not getting it right.

This is my code on the receiving end:

```
public class Panoviewer extends PLView {



public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.load(new PLJSONLoader("res://raw/json_spherical"));
    PLSpherical2Panorama panorama = new PLSpherical2Panorama();
    Intent intentExtras = getIntent();
    String pano = getIntent().getExtras().getString("pano");

    Log.d("MSG", pano);
    //gets R.raw.spherical_pano from previous Activity

    panorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, R.raw.spherical_pano), false));
    this.setPanorama(panorama);

}


}
```

Instead of using direct "R.raw.spherical_pano" I'd like to use the String from previous activity. Simply exchanging it in "panorama.setImage..." doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass R.raw.sherical_pano? Since the resource reference is an int, you can pass it like,

```
int pano = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("key");
```

Then set it like

```
panorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, pano), false));
```

Comment: this works, thanks a lot. I pass an integer from R.raw.spherical_pano on the previous activity and get it in the panoviewer. *happy*

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 int myId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("yourString","raw", context.getPackageName())
```

Then:

```
 panorama.setImage(new PLImage(PLUtils.getBitmap(this, myId), false));
```

Comment: I rad something about mirroroing or whatever in "getIdentifier", which makes it slower to react. I will try it aswell, thanks for the answer.